# How to blob uri in Download Manager?

Tags: javascript, java, android, jquery, kotlin

Is it possible to download using download manager for blob object format. whenever  i  used the uri  having prefix "blob". i am getting this error :

**Android download Manager  can only download Http/https: protocol **

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO. Could you provide us a little more details? You could post the code you are using and the uri (or retracted version if).